# Limit the records sent from magento (1.9) to Algolia

Tags: magento-1.9, algolia

Is there a possibility to limit the records sent from magento (1.9) to Algolia when indexing?

I have found this on their web site but I cannot figure out how/where to configure this index limit in Magento.

https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/accounts-billing/do-you-offer-any-discounts-for-development-staging-environments

> If you want to minimize the impact on pricing, we recommend to only index a subset (10%? or 1%?) of your records in your non-production environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Algolia Magento extensions doesn't handle such restriction. It's a general best-practice but unfortunately, it doesn't apply here.